# Subtracting two numbers (with 2 decimals) results in high decimal number value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand why subtracting two numbers with both 2 decimals causes a value with 18 decimals.

Subtract 185.84 from 185.85 = 0.009999999999990905

```
diff = float(value) - float(device_compare_value)
```

Thanks in advance